# Running test inside testng suite in specific order

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to run tests inside testng  in specific order. Is it possible?

For example here is my testng.xml file. I want to run Chrome test first and then firefox. I dont want them to run parallel.  How to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="mycompany.myapp.local" parallel="none">
<test name="Test Module in Chrome">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="wheretorun" value="local" />
    <parameter name="chrome.driver.path"
        value="/path/to/chromedriver" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="navigateToUserPage" />
                <include name="createUser" />
                <include name="verifySomething1" />
                <include name="verifySomething2" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test Module in Firefox">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="wheretorun" value="local" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="loginWithCreatedUser" />
                <include name="verifySomething1" />
                <include name="verifySomething2" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

I am trying to achieve this: - Create user in 1 test and use the same user in another tests. So I want to run first test and run second only after first one is finished.

Otherwise, is there an option to run something at Suite level .. like create user and set up some data and then run these 2 test?

Many thanks in advance for taking out time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Before I give you an answer, I want to say that you should always strive to run things in parallel.  This will help you in the long run.  Even if that means logging in and out multiple times or creating a pool of test users to be used over and over.  Tests should be short, should test one thing and not be dependent on other tests.

But since the ideal isn't always possible.

"preserve-order If true, the classes in this tag will be run in the same order as found in the XML file."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="mycompany.myapp.local" parallel="tests" thread-count="1" preserve-order="true">
<test name="Setup User" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="wheretorun" value="local" />
    <parameter name="chrome.driver.path"
        value="/path/to/chromedriver" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="createUser" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test Module in Chrome" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="wheretorun" value="local" />
    <parameter name="chrome.driver.path"
        value="/path/to/chromedriver" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="loginWithCreatedUser" />
                <include name="verifySomething1" />
                <include name="verifySomething2" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
<test name="Test Module in Firefox" preserve-order="true">
    <parameter name="selenium.browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="wheretorun" value="local" />
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.TestClass">
            <methods>
                <include name="loginWithCreatedUser" />
                <include name="verifySomething1" />
                <include name="verifySomething2" />
                <include name="logout" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

You can also set the "priority" on each test to insure it runs in the right order.

Again it maybe better to just set up 4 static users, run 4 verifySomething tests and a create user test all in parallel.